# Need help with contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

1. Show that if $w(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$ is continuous on an interval $a \leq t \leq b$, then  $$\int_{-b}^{-a}w(-t)dt=\int_{a}^{b}w(\tau)d\tau$$

Approach: so we are trying to compute $$\int_{c}w(z)dz$$

In this case, the contour can be seen as the real line that ranges from  $a$ to $b$,so we can parametrize this real line by $z=\tau$ where $a\leq \tau \leq b$

In the same manner, it looks like we can parametrize that interval by using $z=-t$. Why are those equivalent?, why can't we say the following

$$\int_{-a}^{-b}w(-t)dt=\int_{a}^{b}w(\tau)d\tau$$

I would like a geometric explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a substitution. Let $\tau= \tau(t) = -t$ then $d \tau = - 1  dt \Rightarrow - d\tau = dt$ and so you have;

$$\int_{-b}^{-a} w(-t) \ dt = - \int_{b}^a w(\tau) \ d\tau = \int_{a}^b w(\tau) \ d \tau$$

Comment: I still don't understand the first integral

Comment: The substitution is the same as a u-substitutuion from first year calculus. Say you wanted to integrate $\int \sin(2x) \ dx$ you would first take $u = 2x$ and go from there.

Comment: Oh ok, got it...